# Not able to print Alert message . Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

My task is to go to the website, https://www.swiggy.com, sign up, and enter some details. I'm able to send details and click sign up but I can't print the alert message "Mobile number already exists".

My code:

```
public class Question14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        driver.get("https://www.swiggy.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.className("r2iyh")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("mobile")).sendKeys("9876543210");
        driver.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("Deepak");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("deepak@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("a-ayg")).click();
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alert = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
        System.out.println(alert);
        WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Mobile number already exists']"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        // js.executeScript(, args)
    }
}
```

[Alert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSEHe.jpg)

Help me to print the alert message in console.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.switchTo().alert()` corresponds to a JavaScript alert but that's not what is on the page. What's on the page is just some HTML called a [toast message](https://www.magicbell.com/blog/what-is-a-toast-message-and-how-do-you-use-it). You just need to add a wait, grab the element, and then print the text. The code below prints, `Mobile number already exists`.

```
public class Question14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        driver.get("https://www.swiggy.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.className("r2iyh")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("mobile")).sendKeys("9876543210");
        driver.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("Deepak");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("deepak@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("a-ayg")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        String message = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("._3--N8"))).getText();
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```